# BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a procedure that looks like the below

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'X')
        UPDATE TABLE X 
        SET ROW = 4
        WHERE NAME = 'STEVE'

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Y')
        UPDATE TABLE Y
        SET ROW = 5
        WHERE NAME = 'ART'
END
```

Would I need to add a BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN encapsulation if I wanted the two IF statements to be evaluated in atomicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use a transaction if you want atomicity.

Answer (score 1):

Using BEGIN/END TRAN won't guarantee that the two IF statements are both evaluated. If the first SELECT/UPDATE fails with an error, the second SELECT/UPDATE will likely not be executed.

But BEGIN/END TRAN will guarantee that both UPDATE statements are executed or neither of  them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might encounter a deeper problem with this  - if table X doesn't exist then the procedure will fail to compile because you have a reference to it in the UPDATE